# JavaScript Sort Function with more than one criteria

Tags: javascript, sorting

Here is a sample of what I am sorting:

```
[
  ['Zed Jones', '24 Nov 2017 2:00 PM'],
  ['Jack Mo', '25 Nov 2017 5:00 PM'],
  ['John Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM'],
  ['Bob Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM']
]
```

Here is my desired output:

```
[
  ['Zed Jones', '24 Nov 2017 2:00 PM'],
  ['Bob Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM'],
  ['John Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM'],
  ['Jack Mo', '25 Nov 2017 5:00 PM']
]
```

Notice how the output is sorted by day, hour, and first letter of first name

Here is my code below. I have been able to sort by day and hour pretty easily but I am having trouble finding a way to compare and place first letter of first name:

```
function sortTable(data) {
  return data.sort((elem1, elem2) => {
    var dateA      = new Date(elem1[1])
      , dateB      = new Date(elem2[1])

    return dateA.getHours() - dateB.getHours() + dateB.setHours(0) - dateA.setHours(0);
  });
}
```

I have tried to sort once by date and then perform another sort function comparing the first letter of each first name, but I am having issues as it does not properly sort the data:

```
function sortTable(data) {
  // Sort by date and time
  data = data.sort((elem1, elem2) => {
    var dateA      = new Date(elem1[1])
      , dateB      = new Date(elem2[1])

    return dateA.getHours() - dateB.getHours() + dateB.setHours(0) - dateA.setHours(0);
  });

  // Then sort by name and return data
  return data.sort((elem1, elem2) => {
    var name1 = elem1[0]
      , name2 = elem2[0]
      , let1
      , let2;

    // Check that we have a name available
    if (name1 !== undefined) let1 = name1.charAt(0);
    if (name2 !== undefined) let2 = name2.charAt(0);

      return let1 < let2;
  });
 }
```

In what ways can I modify this code to achieve my desired output? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't use date the way you do - you should parse the string!

Comment: Your second sort would override the result of first one. Put the two comparisons into one sort function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the delta of the second element as date difference and take the first character for sorting if the delta is zero of the date

```js
var data = [['Zed Jones', '24 Nov 2017 2:00 PM'], ['Jack Mo', '25 Nov 2017 5:00 PM'], ['John Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM'], ['Bob Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM']];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return new Date(a[1]) - new Date(b[1]) || a[0][0] > b[0][0] || -(a[0][0] < b[0][0]);
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Why do we need this part? `-(a[0][0] < b[0][0])` ?

Comment: it sorts by the first letter.

Comment: @alfasin, that is not advisable, because sort expects three values, instead of two. the problem could be if you like to sort reverse, then you could get a wrong order.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand - I don't see three values, I see a function that's passed to `sort` which takes two objects and returns a diff between the date or a diff between the first characters or... a diff between the first characters. I'm not very good with JS - am I reading it wrong?

Comment: [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) expects a value of smaller than zero, if `a` is smaller than `b`, zero, if `a` and `b` is equal or a value greater than zero, if a is greater than `b` for sorting ascending., if you just take two values, like a boolean which resolves to `0` or `1`, then you omit the negative values, which are necessary for a stable sort (is that is possible).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I accepted this answer because it was clean and it works. Quick question: What if I wanted to change the date criteria to have the days sorted in descending order but the times sorted in ascending order. i.e. the array `[['Zed Jones', '24 Nov 2017 2:00 PM'], ['Jack Mo', '25 Nov 2017 5:00 PM'], ['John Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM'], ['Bob Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM']]` would be `[['Bob Phil', 25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM],['John Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM'],  ['Jack Mo', '25 Nov 2017 5:00 PM'], ['Zed Jones', '24 Nov 2017 2:00 PM']]`

Answer (score 0):

We should check the date-diff and only if it's zero - we'll sort by the first character, see code-comments:

```js
var data = [
  ['Zed Jones', '24 Nov 2017 2:00 PM'],
  ['Jack Mo', '25 Nov 2017 5:00 PM'],
  ['John Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM'],
  ['Bob Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM']
];

function sortTable(data) {
    
  // Then sort by name and return data
  return data.sort((elem1, elem2) => {
      var dateA      = new Date(elem1[1])
        , dateB      = new Date(elem2[1]);
      var name1 = elem1[0]
        , name2 = elem2[0]
        , let1
        , let2;

    var dateDiff = dateA - dateB; // compare dates first

    // if we have a date-difference we'll use it
    if (dateDiff !== 0) {
        return dateDiff;
    }

    // only if no date-diff - compare names!
    if (name1 !== undefined) let1 = name1.charAt(0);
    if (name2 !== undefined) let2 = name2.charAt(0);

      return let1 > let2; // change the comparison from < to >
  });
 }

 sortTable(data);
 console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.prototype.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
var input = [['Zed Jones', '24 Nov 2017 2:00 PM'],
  ['Jack Mo', '25 Nov 2017 5:00 PM'],
  ['John Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM'],
  ['Bob Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM'],
  ['Bob Phil', '01 Dec 2017 01:00 AM'],
  ['1Bob Phil', '01 Dec 2017 01:00 AM'],
  ['asdf df', '01 Dec 1999 01:30 PM']];

//Now with the help of `localeCompare`

function sortTable(data) {
  return data.sort((elem1, elem2) => {
    var dateA      = new Date(elem1[1])
      , dateB      = new Date(elem2[1])
      , nameA     = elem1[0]
      , nameB      = elem2[0]
      , datecomp      = dateA - dateB
      , namecomp      = nameA.localeCompare(nameB);

    return datecomp > 0 ? datecomp : datecomp + namecomp;
  });
}

//See results:-

sortTable(input);
console.log(input);
```